# Error 401 (Unauthorized) Keycloak with Vue js

Tags: vue.js, keycloak

I'm making a GET request to keycloak server to obtain all users.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${Vue.prototype.$keycloak.token}`);
myHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  };
fetch('http://localhost:8081/auth/admin/realms/test-realms/users', requestOptions)
```

I was trying with admin-cli too...

fetch('http://localhost:8081/auth/admin/realms/admin-cli/users', requestOptions)

I always get 401 (unauthorized).

Comment: Hmm in general 401 means that the connected database -which contains the user data- cannot find the passed user data. There are multiple reasons. In example the passed json data does not match the expected format, the data are unknown, etc. .

Comment: Maybe you wanted to send this data with method POST instead of method GET.

Comment: Your realms are called `test-realms` / `admin-cli`, really? General advice: use the developer tools of your browser to inspect the full details of you request and compare that to what the Keycloak Admin Console is doing.

Comment: tried method post and it backs the same result.

Comment: test-realms is a name that I invented to put in here, and admin-cli is a client default on keycloak, I tested because in some posts people were saying that to obtain users, we have to use that client. In the browser it only returns, "unauthorized" and in keycloak admin console, I dont know how to see it. I opened the "bin/standalone"... In ther I don't have any info of login atempts

Comment: I would create dedicated client with minimal permissions for security reasons. admin-cli has quite powerful permissions by default. 401 may also indicates that token is expired. Print used token and verify it. Any CORS issues in the console?

Comment: I was having problems with CORS, and after inumerous trys I manage to take it off.

Comment: I genereated the token instantly before the request. I used postman and have the same issue